# How to change values as a user enters in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="box2">Enter taxable income :-
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="entry" onchange="calc()" required></input>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="calc()"></input>
    <p>Income :-
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="res"></input>
    </p>
    <p>Your tax bracket :-
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="tbra"></input>
    </p>
    <p>Tax :-
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="tax"></input>
    </p>
    <p>Education Cess :-
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="ec"></input>
    </p>
    <p>Higher Education Cess :-
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="hec"></input>
    </p>
    <p>Total Tax :-
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="ttax"></input>
    </p>
</div>
```

In the above form how can I change values in the text boxes as I enter new values.  Currently either I have to press the enter key (onchange) or press the submit button.  I am using JavaScript functions.

Comment: `</input>` is invalid HTML markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/deregayiqo/1/edit?html,js,output)***

Have you thought about *"What if a user `paste`s a value"*?

Also `<input />` is invalid HTML markup,
inputs are [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) therefore should not have a closing tag.

HTML:

```
    <div class="box2">
        Enter taxable income:<br>
        <input type="text" id="entry" required>
        <p>
            Income:<br>
            <input type="text" id="res">
        </p>
        <p>Your tax bracket:<br>
            <input type="text" id="tbra">
        </p>
        <p>
            Tax:<br>
            <input type="text" id="tax">
        </p>
        <p>
            Education Cess:<br>
            <input type="text" id="ec">
        </p>
        <p>
            Higher Education Cess:<br>
            <input type="text" id="hec">
        </p>
        <p>
            Total Tax:<br>
            <input type="text" id="ttax">
        </p>
    </div>
```

As you can see I've removed the inline JS which is considered bad practice.
Move all your logic into JS:

```
function id(v){return document.getElementById(v);}

var entry = id("entry");
var res   = id("res");

function calc() {
    res.value = parseInt(entry.value, 10) + 100;
}

entry.addEventListener("input", calc, false);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I will have to learn more about JavaScript to understand your function. Just started learning.  Please suggest a good book to start with.  Currently referring the  W3Schools tutorial - http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: Checked your jsBin demo.  Copied it.  Its not working on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `onkeypress` event instead, which activates whenever the user types, instead of when the form actually changes (loses focus):

```
<input type="text" id="entry" onkeypress="calc()" />
```

Comment: Thanks Scimonster.  'onkeypress' is working but the first digit entered is not captured.